# Using ANTLR grammar based parser in SonarQube plugin to create new language support

Tags: sonarqube, antlr

We're planning on adding Fortran language support to SonarQube by creating a SonarQube Fortran plugin.

We already have an existing ANTLR grammar and generated parser for the Fortran language. Can we use this as the plugin's parser and build a rule engine parsing the AST generated by ANTLR? The official supported solution seems to be to use SonarSouce's SSLR for the parsing. I could find some older projects ([Delphi support](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Delphi+Plugin) and [Checkstyle](http://www.sonarqube.org/already-158-checkstyle-and-pmd-rules-deprecated-by-sonarqube-java-rules/)) built on top of an ANTLR grammar, but those are both deprecated, so it got me wondering whether using ANTLR is still supported.

Just making sure before we start planning this in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use SSLR to create a language plugin for SonarQube: the SonarQube APIs are independent of any parsing technology.

The [SonarQube CheckStyle plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Checkstyle+Plugin) is still supported, even if a good number of its rules were rewritten in the SonarQube Java plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I think this i a little outdated, now the sonar-groovy plugin is a better approach IMHO if you want to develop a plugin with antlr: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-groovy